# How to stop jQuery .ajax() execution when success is false?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code which works.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "includes/process.php",
     data: "captcha=" + captcha,
     success: function(data) {
         if(data == 'true')
             alert("OK");
         else
             alert("not ok");
     }
});
```

However I have some more code after that like:

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&message=' + message;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "bin/process.php",
    data: dataString,
    ...
    ...
    ...etc
```

However, I need to stop the script when success:function(data) is false.

So, I thought that `return false;` should stop the execution

```
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == 'true') {
            alert("OK");
        } else { 
            alert("not ok"); 
            return false; 
        }
    }
```

, however it is not working and the code after `$.ajax` is executed anyway.

How to stop the script when the `success` is `false`?

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:** 
I have another ajax call which I want to execute when success is true:

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&message=' + message;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "bin/process.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
       alert ('mail was sent OK');                                 
    }
});
```

How to execute this code only after success of the first ajax call?

Comment: If it is erroring, then you can extend your `.ajax` function using `error:function(data) {}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your extra code should be in the callback itself.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "includes/process.php",
    data: "captcha=" + captcha,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'true') {
            alert("OK");
            // more code
            var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&message=' + message;
            // ... second ajax call
        } else {
            alert("not ok");
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: But I have another ajax call there, check my post I have updated my code. Will this be running?

Comment: @marian, you can do the other ajax call inside the `if` of the `success` of the first ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

You could also add `async:false` to your AJAX call. This way, the code after won't execute until the request has ended. `return false` won't do anything either, but you could set a flag in the success function.

```
var isOk = false;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,    // prevent the asynchronous call
    url: "includes/process.php",
    data: "captcha=" + captcha,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.length) {
            alert("OK");
            isOk = true;
        }
    }
});

if (isOk) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can 
1) add your additional code to the callback success function

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "includes/process.php",
       data: "captcha=" + captcha,
       success:function(data){
          if(data=='true') {
            alert("OK");
            //continue here
            var datastring = ...
          }
          else
            alert("not ok");
       }
```

});

2) change the ajax call to not be asynchronous by adding this option to the .ajax call

```
var isSuccess = false;
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "includes/process.php",
       data: "captcha=" + captcha,
       success:function(data){
            isSuccess = (data=='true');
       },
       async:   false
   });
```

Then you can set a var in your success function to tell the rest of your code whether to continue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$.ajax()` is asynchronous, code after that will execute anyway. You can put the code in `success` handler. That way, it'll run only if its successful.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is an asynchronous call (hence the first 'A'). This means that jQuery makes your request and then goes on about its business while waiting for the call to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The code after `$.ajax` is usually executed before the `success` function, because the `$.ajax` call is asynchronous. If you keep it asyncronous, you cannot stop the execution of the other code. You can set in the `success` function value of a variable in the outer scope and use syncronous code. But maybe it's better to move it in a function, called by the `success` callback? Anyway, to get better answer, please post more code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "includes/process.php",
    data: "captcha=" + captcha,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.length) {
            alert("OK");
            doMoreStuff(data);
        }
    }
});

function doMoreStuff(data){
    // Code here will only be executed if ajax call is successful.
}
```